# Localization of OS X Today Extension fails in Widget-Simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, localization, today-extension

I created an OS X Today extension and want to test my localization. But the Widget-Simulator refuses to accept my language selection.

I created `*.strings` files for text which comes from source code and is translated through:

```
NSLocalizedString("Some text", tableName: "nameOfTheStringFile", comment: "foo")
```

Here's a screenshot of some structure of the string files:

[image]

The whole project contains 8 localized files. But only two of them are related to the widget. The general `Info.plist` and a file named `TranslationsWidget.strings` as shown above.

All languages have been added through the language list in the projects info tab and it looks like this:

[image]

Now what happens in the simulator is, the simulator itself is translated. All the menu items of the simulator will appear in whatever language I have chosen in my scheme. But the content of the widget is not. I don't think it is a problem with my configuration or code, because the widget actually is translated: To the system language, which is German, while the development language is english. So it's not simply not translating, but to the wrong language.

The containing main application (a Today Extension must be packed inside a normal app) translates just fine to whatever I chose in the corresponding Scheme.

I not only ran *Product -> Clean* from the menu several times, I as well deleted all derived data:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf *
```

Not only because of that I am sure it is not a somehow cached thingy. As well if I update the German translation strings, the widget gets updated on the next run.

I tested the localization of the widget works perfectly by changing the system language. It just doesn't work in the Widget-Simulator by changing the language in the Scheme.

I now have to override the German translation to test other languages, which is highly annoying. Is this a common issue? Anybody found a fix?

Comment: Can you post your `*string` files and maybe a screenshot of them in the Project Navigator view in Xcode? Perhaps there is a problem there. If you don't format the file properly it will break and just use what you have in the code. A line in the '`.string` should look like this `"key" = "value";` (note the semi-colon at the end)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The format of the string files is correct. When the semicolon is missing or something else is not right, Xcode will actually complain about the broken string file and not build/start the app. Also, the localization works when the system language is changed. So this is more a problem of the Widget-Simulator always using the system language - I think.

Comment: Interesting that poorly formatted localization file will complain for you - it did not for me just the other day :(. One thing I often change when I think it might be a "cached thingy" is the product id, so the system thinks it is a new app. Not sure if it will work in your case though.

Comment: Yeah, that's Xcode with all its random features... ;-) I tried changing the Product Identifier. Good idea, but unfortunately the same result.

Comment: The only other thing I could guess would be somehow your project is set up for the single localization file (base localization), but not the others... I am sure you have checked it, but the `Info` tab in the `Project` settings. It should list the languages there from memory. Random suggestions I know, but it seems like one of those problems...

Comment: Nope, the localization settings are fine. I added all languages through the projects info tab. I added a screenshot above (not possible in a comment). There you as well can see the development language is actually English, while the Widget-Simulator uses the System language German. Also the "Base" `*.strings` files contain english text. So it really localizes the content, just with the wrong language.

Comment: Oh, and what I also forget to mention is, the main application where the Today Extension is packed in, translates perfectly to what I chose in the Scheme. Updated the question above with that info.

Comment: I just had another "experience" with this totally f*** localization in Xcode. This time though with the main application. The localization just stopped working - without any change. Period, no change! I have my code in version control so I see if stuff would had been changed accidentally. There as well are no files which are not versioned inside my project folder. I work with git from command line so I know what's going on. Just to be triple sure, I restored my project state from yesterday, and localization was not working. Just for the fun I duplicated the Scheme. A 1:1 copy: And this works!

Comment: And it worked exactly once and now it's broken again. I'm getting crazy with this Xcode crap!

Comment: lol - I feel for you. If you did not change code, then that would point to something being cleaned from the build folder. However, you have already mentioned that you tried this with no luck. The only other experience I have had which is similar is with an app icon which would not update. I had to change the product ID before it would get the new one...

Comment: The problem with the main application is solved - for now. I think it might be related to the base localization. When you look at the screenshot of the files structure above you see I did not have a "Base" localization file. The reason is, I removed it, because I figured it would be redundant with the English files, as that's the development language. With Both, Base AND English available, the info tab would show me 16 localized files for English. So I deleted the base files. But I didn't do it recently, that was  days ago when I started with localization.

Comment: This seems to have been the source for the unpredictable results in the main app. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. I re-added the base files and I have no problems since then. But that might be just coincidence. It used to work for days w/o those base files. Anyway, unfortunately adding the base files did not change the behavior of the Widget Simulator. Still the content of the Extension is in German/System language while the menu of the Simulator reflects the language I had chosen in the Scheme. It's not that bad. I only have one single `.strings` file I have to swap. Still annoying.